# Insert a table that contains values provided by a filter formula

Tags: excel, filter

The problem that I am facing right now is the following:

I am using the filter formula to return me a specific range of values (basically information from 5 different columns). However, I have other 7 columns on the right side that I will need to input manual data (so, 5 columns given by the filter formula and other 7 that I will need to complete).

The problem is that after filtering and manually inputting all data for the missing columns, I will need to insert a table including all 12 columns.  But when I try to insert a table it gives me the #SPILL! error.

How can I insert a table that contains values provided by a filter formula?

Comment: Spill array formulas are not currently supported in Excel tables. You might have to resort to VBA. This article might be useful: https://exceloffthegrid.com/using-dynamic-arrays-with-other-excel-features/

Comment: You could use array formulas to spill down the rows to match your filter spill range.

Comment: Also, I assume you mean 12 columns. Why not just make a different spill range with all 12 columns? If it has to be table you're kind of out of luck.

Comment: @pgSystemTester The problem is that I will need to manually input data after having the filtered value, and changing that will affect everything =( and yes it has to be table because I will need to create a query with this information

Comment: Perhaps a dynamic named range? Or like Brayan Rock said, vba or TypeScript would probably do it.

Comment: Yeah I already gave up, I will try to start again my analysis and find other solution for it! But thank you